# How to use "Link A" php - joomla

Tags: php, joomla, hyperlink, article

I'm having trouble using another article link in my "slideshow". 
In the article in Joomla it's possible to add 3 links, Link A, Link B and Link C. 
I'm sure it's is possible to use theese links  with the PHP, but I really can't find out how.

At the moment, each article in the slideshow, is linking to itself. It looks like this:

```
    <a target="_<?php echo $openTarget ;?>" title="<?php echo $row->title;?>" href="<?php echo $row->link;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?></a>
```

And I have tried to change the link, to linkA

```
    <?php foreach ($articles as $key=>$article):
            $articleImage = json_decode($article->images);
            $articleLinks = json_decode($article->urls);
            $link = NULL;
            switch ($linkTo) {
                case 'urlta':
                    $link = $article->link;
                    break;
                case 'urla':
                    $link = $articleLinks->urla;
                    break;  
                case 'urlb':
                    $link = $articleLinks->urlb;
                    break;
                case 'urlc':
                    $link = $articleLinks->urlc;
                    break;
                case 'unurl':
                    $link = null;
                    break;
            }   
    ?>
```

Can anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

Your starting point was correct, the only thing you missed is the variable $linkTo. I can't see that is set in you quote.

if you simple want always to use "Link A" as target url for your slideshow you could use this code:

```
<?php
  foreach ($articles as $key=>$article):
    $articleLinks = json_decode($article->urls);
    $link = $articleLinks->urla;
    ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $article->title;?>" href="<?php echo $link;?>"><?php echo $article->title;?></a>
    <?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

If you like to use "Link A" only if it is set you could check if it exists:

```
<?php
  foreach ($articles as $key=>$article):
    $articleLinks = json_decode($article->urls);
    $link = ($articleLinks->urla ? $articleLinks->urla : $article->link);
    ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $article->title;?>" href="<?php echo $link;?>"><?php echo $article->title;?></a>
    <?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE id = ART-ID";
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadAssoc();
$urls = json_decode($row['urls']);
?>

<?php echo $urls->{'urla'}; ?>
```

`ART-ID` is the id of the article you are trying to get the URL from.